# How to underline a specific word in a string for a React Native button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using a **Button** component from `react-native-elements` and for the `title` prop I would like to underline one of the words, is this possible?

`button.js:`

```
    <Button
      buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
      titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
      containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
      title={title}
      onPress={onPress}
      disabled={disabled}
      disabledStyle={[styles.disabledStyle]}
    />
```

I'm using it like this:

```
    <Button
      title={'First line \nSecond line'} // <- How to underline First & Second?
      onPress={() => console.log('pressed button')}
    />
```

How do I underline the words *First* and *Second*?

I tried doing `` title={`${First} line \n${Second} line`} `` where First and Second is a `<Text style={{textDecoration: 'underline}}>First</Text>` but I'm getting `[object, Object]` since it's not an expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Button>` implementation in React Native Elements indeed does support passing component as [`title` property value](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/button#title) - but in your code you try to pass those as text. That's what you might try instead:

```
const ButtonTitle = (
  <>
    <Text style={{textDecoration: 'underline'}}>First</Text>
    <Text style={{textDecoration: 'underline'}}>Second</Text>
  </>
)

<Button title={ButtonTitle} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, I generally will use `React.ReactNode` as the type for `title` instead of a string. This will be backwards-compatible, as strings are valid `ReactNode`s, but it also allows you to do this:

```
// style example
const style = Stylesheet.create({
  underline: { textDecoration: 'underline' },
});
```

```
// Implementation in component
title={
<Text>
  <Text style={style.underline}>
    First line
  </Text>
  <Text style={style.underline}>
    Second line
  </Text>
</Text>
}
```

Reminder that the original will also still work as `ReactNode` is a type which includes `string`:

```
title={'First line \nSecond line'}
```